# I wanted to create a project where user just fill the form and from that form detail subdomain automatically creates with premade WordPress site data

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, cpanel, wildcard

There will be one form where user fill their details and with their form data, one subdomain has to be automatically created and WordPress website I have created already should be installed on that subdomain automatically.
How can I achieve this? I have tried wildcard domains but facing issue since I am not from coding background. Please suggest me if there is another better option available or if wildcard is good then how can I make this possible in wildcard.

Here is the basic version, where subdomain get created will user request and welcome message will be shown at created subdomain

**Index.php**

```
<!-- /home4/hsentbbq/public_html/index.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create Subdomain</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create a New Subdomain</h1>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label for="new_subdomain">New Subdomain:</label>
    <input type="text" name="new_subdomain" id="new_subdomain" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Subdomain">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
// /home4/hsentbbq/public_html/process.php

// Validate form submission
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["new_subdomain"])) {
    // Load existing user-generated subdomains from JSON file
    $subdomainsJsonPath = '/home4/hsentbbq/public_html/_wildcard_.coderedge.org/subdomains.json';
    $subdomains = json_decode(file_get_contents($subdomainsJsonPath), true);

    // Get new subdomain from the form
    $newSubdomain = strtolower(trim($_POST["new_subdomain"]));

    // Check if the subdomain already exists
    if (array_key_exists($newSubdomain, $subdomains)) {
        echo "Subdomain '$newSubdomain' already exists.";
    } else {
        // Add the new subdomain to the user-generated subdomains
        $fullSubdomain = $newSubdomain . '.coderedge.org';
        $subdomains[$fullSubdomain] = "Welcome to $fullSubdomain!";

        // Save the updated subdomains to the JSON file
        file_put_contents($subdomainsJsonPath, json_encode($subdomains, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

        echo "Subdomain '$fullSubdomain' created successfully!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid form submission.";
}
?>
```

***wildcard*.domain.com**

```
<?php
// /home4/hsentbbq/public_html/_wildcard_.coderedge.org/index.php

// Load user-generated subdomains from JSON file
$subdomainsJsonPath = '/home4/hsentbbq/public_html/_wildcard_.coderedge.org/subdomains.json';
$subdomains = json_decode(file_get_contents($subdomainsJsonPath), true);

// Get the requested subdomain from the URL
$requestSubdomain = strtolower(trim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

// Validate if the requested subdomain is user-generated
if (array_key_exists($requestSubdomain, $subdomains)) {
    // Display content for the user-generated subdomain
    echo $subdomains[$requestSubdomain];
} else {
    // Display a generic message for non-user-generated subdomains
    echo "Invalid subdomain. Please enter a valid subdomain.";
}
?>
```

There will be one form where user fill their details and with their form data, one subdomain has to be automatically created and WordPress website I have created already should be installed on that subdomain automatically.
How can I achieve this? I have tried wildcard domains but facing issue since I am not from coding background. Please suggest me if there is another better option available or if wildcard is good then how can I make this possible in wildcard.

Here is the basic version, where subdomain get created will user request and welcome message will be shown at created subdomain

**Index.php**

```
<!-- /home4/hsentbbq/public_html/index.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create Subdomain</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create a New Subdomain</h1>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <label for="new_subdomain">New Subdomain:</label>
    <input type="text" name="new_subdomain" id="new_subdomain" required>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Subdomain">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
// /home4/hsentbbq/public_html/process.php

// Validate form submission
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["new_subdomain"])) {
    // Load existing user-generated subdomains from JSON file
    $subdomainsJsonPath = '/home4/hsentbbq/public_html/_wildcard_.coderedge.org/subdomains.json';
    $subdomains = json_decode(file_get_contents($subdomainsJsonPath), true);

    // Get new subdomain from the form
    $newSubdomain = strtolower(trim($_POST["new_subdomain"]));

    // Check if the subdomain already exists
    if (array_key_exists($newSubdomain, $subdomains)) {
        echo "Subdomain '$newSubdomain' already exists.";
    } else {
        // Add the new subdomain to the user-generated subdomains
        $fullSubdomain = $newSubdomain . '.coderedge.org';
        $subdomains[$fullSubdomain] = "Welcome to $fullSubdomain!";

        // Save the updated subdomains to the JSON file
        file_put_contents($subdomainsJsonPath, json_encode($subdomains, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

        echo "Subdomain '$fullSubdomain' created successfully!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid form submission.";
}
?>
```

***wildcard*.domain.com**

```
<?php
// /home4/hsentbbq/public_html/_wildcard_.coderedge.org/index.php

// Load user-generated subdomains from JSON file
$subdomainsJsonPath = '/home4/hsentbbq/public_html/_wildcard_.coderedge.org/subdomains.json';
$subdomains = json_decode(file_get_contents($subdomainsJsonPath), true);

// Get the requested subdomain from the URL
$requestSubdomain = strtolower(trim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

// Validate if the requested subdomain is user-generated
if (array_key_exists($requestSubdomain, $subdomains)) {
    // Display content for the user-generated subdomain
    echo $subdomains[$requestSubdomain];
} else {
    // Display a generic message for non-user-generated subdomains
    echo "Invalid subdomain. Please enter a valid subdomain.";
}
?>
```